# redirect data form tunnel to another network

Tags: networking, iptables, redirection, tunnel

I have Linux computer with eth0(192.168.1.20/24) and tun0(10.8.0.6/24) interface.
I am sending data through tunnel to Linux computer in the specific port and want to redirect all data to another computer, witch ip is 192.168.1.25/24.

how could I solve this task?

Comment: You may have a look at socat : http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:
1) Enable IP forwaring first of all:

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

2) Since they are on different networks not to poke with routing tables od both sides you could use NAT. Use iptables to forward the specific port (change INPORT and OUTPORT as needed):

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.20 --dport INPORT -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.25:OUTPORT

You can get more detailed informations for example here: http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial